# Emacs 24.5 : replace pattern in a specific column of a CSV file

Tags: csv, emacs, emacs24

I want to replace in the 3rd column ONLY the pattern 'foo' by 'bar' of the following CSV file. Is it possible to do this with emacs or do I need to write a script to do this ?

```
foo;bbb;foo;
foo;bbbbbbbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbb;foo;
foo;bbbbbbbbbbbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbb;foo;
```

So, the expedted result would be :

```
foo;bbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbbbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbbbbbbbb;bar;
foo;bbbbbb;bar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With csv mode: https://github.com/emacsmirror/csv-mode

```
M-x csv-transpose
Then your column is a line, so you can select as region and do a query-replace on the region or use narrow-to-region or ...
M-x csv-transpose
```

  -